# Should I worry about putting a large amount of data on the Windows Clipboard?

Tags: windows, clipboard

If you try to close a Microsoft Office application when you've got a ton of its stuff on the clipboard (e.g. a whole word doc), it prompts you to ask if you would like to access that data after the application is closed.

In this day and age, does it really matter if I have say 10MB of stuff on the clipboard?

As I write my image processing app, should I follow the same rule as Office, or just forget about it and leave the data there?

Comment: belongs on superuser.com, this is not a programming question

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I favor just forgetting about it and leaving it there.  I've always found the MS Word approach more annoying than useful.

Comment: I definitely find it annoying too.  Was wondering if they do that for any true technical reason...?

Comment: It's probably a security issue. If you're working on a confidential, encrypted, password-protected document, you probably don't want the two paragraphs you copy-pasted to the next page left on your clipboard after you exit. :)

Comment: It's because office uses delayed rendering to allow the copy operation to happen extremely quickly and only render the format(s) that get pasted. @NickLewis Nothing to do with security or it would use private formats rather than registered formats, preventing other applications from seeing the data even while the application was open.

Answer (score 1):

The reason word is asking about this is that it uses [Delayed Rendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649014(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Delayed_Rendering) for the clipboard. This allows word to only create the formats that are requested upon a paste operation. However, any formats on the clipboard that were created with delayed rendering will disappear if the program exits without rendering them. In the case of excel, rendering thousands of empty cells in RTF would take megabytes of space, even though the actual data is tiny. Thus it asks whether you want the data rendered to the clipboard or if you're fine with losing it.

For your own application, the question then becomes: should I use delayed rendering? The answer depends on how long it take you to render in the various formats you'd like to support. If you're only supporting one format that renders quickly, odds are there's not going to be an advantage to delayed rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing things on the clipboard without the user requesting it then you might just annoy a few people :)

Otherwise, yeah, just leave the data there.

Answer (score 0):

[**How To Erase Windows Clipboard Data**](http://erase-internet-history.com/clear-windows-history/erase-windows-clipboard-data/) and Why.

> any one who has access to the computer can easily see the clipboard information.

I'd guess, malware today would also be snooping there.

<sub>this question might be more suitable on **superuser**.</sub>